# Prove that $f'(0)=5$

Tags: real-analysis

Let the function $h:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be bounded. Define $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=2+5x+x^2h(x)$. Prove that $f(0)=2$ and $f'(0)=5$.

I think$f(0)=2$ is pretty obvious. Next $$f'(0)= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2+5x+x^2h(x)-2}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{5+2xh(x)+x^2h'(x)}{1}=5,$$ right? In that case why do we need h to be bounded?

Comment: Try $h(x) = 1/x^2$ for $x \ne 0$,$0$ for $x=0$ for a counter example.

Comment: Why the $2xh+x^2h$ in last equality ? Where does that comes from all of a sudden ?

Comment: @zwim L'hopitale's rule, there was a typo, edited

Comment: You are not allowed to use L'Hospital's Rule because you don't know anything about $h$ apart from it being bounded. The fraction under limit simplifies to $5+xh(x)$ and this tends to $5$ as $xh(x) \to 0$ (and this is where we need $h$ to be bounded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding your specific question, you used the fact that $$x\cdot h(x)\to 0$$
as $x \to 0$.

The property that let you conclude this is that *zero times bounded goes to zero*. More precisely: if $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a$ and $g(x)$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $a$, then
$$f(x)\cdot g(x)\to 0,$$
as $x\to a$. (A detail: none of $f$ or $g$ need to be defined at $x=a$.)

If $g$ is not bounded, the conclusion may or may not be true, as happens when $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac 1 {x^2}$, for which $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$, but
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\cdot g(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1x=\infty.$$

This is possible, since $g(x)$ is not bounded in a neighborhood of $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $h(x)$ is differentiable, then $f(x)=2+5x+x^2h(x)$is differentiable and $$f'(x) = 5+2xh(x)+x^2h'(x)$$

If $h(x)$ and $h'(x)$ are bounded at $x=0$ , then $f'(0) = 5$.

Comment: Now I noticed that there is no assumption about differentiability of $h(x)$, how do we find $f'(x)$ then?

Comment: Really no need to add the differentiable condition for $h$, given it is bounded. I think the purpose of this exercise is to unleash the very original definition of the derivative, instead of carrying out algebraic calculation laws.